# How to find element attribute using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Suppose I have the the following xml:

```
<package xmlns="http://example/namespace">
    <rating system="au-oflc">PG</rating>
    ...
</package>
```

To get the text of an element in the above, I am doing the following:

```
from lxml import entree
f = open('/Users/David/Desktop/metadata.xml')
metadata_contents = f.read()
node = etree.fromstring(metadata_contents)
rating = node.xpath('//t:rating/text()', namespaces = {'t':'http://example/namespace'})
>>> rating
['PG']
```

How would I get the value "au-oflc" ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to retrieve the node itself, not its text:

```
rating = node.xpath('//t:rating', namespaces = {'t':'http://example/namespace'})
print rating[0].attrib['system']
```

Answer (score 4):

[georg](https://users/989121/georg)'s [answer](/a/9334849/493161) assumes all `rating` elements will have a `system` tag. if that is not necessarily the case, using `rating[0].attrib.get('system')` will avoid a KeyError.

Answer (score 2):

You can also access the attribute using XPath:

```
system = node.xpath('//t:rating/@system', namespaces = {'t':'http://example/namespace'})
print system[0]
```